# find expected number of draws

Tags: probability

This question comes from a Quant interview prep.
I sample from the Uniform(0,1) distribution. My friend repeatedly samples from
the same distribution until she obtains a number higher than mine. How many samples
is she expected to make?
My original thought was:

$\Pr(\text{draws} = 1) = \int_0^1 \int_{x_1}^1 \mathrm{d}x_2\,  \mathrm{d}x_1 = 1/2$

$\Pr(\text{draws} = 2) = \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{x_1} \int_{x_1}^{1}  \mathrm{d}x_3 \, \mathrm{d}x_2 \, \mathrm{d}x_1 = 1/6$

and by calculating expected value:

$\mathbb E(\text{draws}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\Pr(\text{draws} = n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\times(1/n-1/(n+1))$

I found expected value is infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Given your first draw is $x$, the probability of beating the draw is $(1-x)$ and therefore the expected number of draws is $1/(1-x)$. And $\int\limits_0^1 1/(1-x) dx = \infty$. So you are indeed correct.