# expected number of draws until greater than first sample

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Aaron samples from a uniform$(0,1)$ distribution. Then Brooke repeatedly samples from
the same distribution until she obtains a number higher than Aaron’s. How many samples
is she expected to make?

I need some help reconciling two solutions that I found:

For the first solution:

[image]

For the second Solution (found two on math.stackexchange):

[find expected number of draws](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774322/find-expected-number-of-draws)

[How many tries to get higher number than uniform random variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716534/how-many-tries-to-get-higher-number-than-uniform-random-variable)

Therefore, my question is this:

1. If the first solution is correct, I don't quite understand the step of using the inverse function to find the distribution of $N = g(A)$, and the reason behind taking the derivative of $\frac{d}{dn}g^{-1}(n)$.
2. If the second solution is correct, we get the expected number of draws as $\infty$, does that make sense ?

Personally, the approach in the second solution makes sense to me, but I am unable to come up with an intuition for why the number of draws is $\infty$, where as the first solution provides a finite number.

Could someone help confirm this ?

Comment: The first solution is clearly incorrect because $N\ne g(A)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E:=\mathsf{E}[N\mid A]$. Then for $z\ge 1$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(E\le z)=\mathsf{P}(A\le 1-z^{-1})=1-z^{-1},
$$
and, therefore, the pdf of $E$ is given by
$$
f_E(z)=\frac{d}{dz}(1-z^{-1})=z^{-2}1_{[1,\infty)}.
$$
Then
$$
\mathsf{E}[N]=\mathsf{E}[E]=\int_1^{\infty} \frac{z}{z^2}\, dz=\infty.
$$
The same result can be obtained directly, i.e.,
$$
\mathsf{E}[E]=\mathsf{E}\left[\frac{1}{1-A}\right]=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-a}\,da=\infty.
$$

Comment: Is your answer contradictory to this one here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1835385/458420

Comment: @JinhuaWang No. The question here is different.